# Drag and drop programmatically - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable, rubaxa-sortable

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a9rkz2pg/

The blocks in the widgets group can be dragged using the mouse drag event, as a clone and dropped into Group 1 or Group 2,3,4.. (appears on click of plus button)

But, is there a way this can be done programmatically, either by knowing the id/class of the draggable or it’s text content?

```
new Sortable($('#widgets-1')[0], {
  group: {
    name: 'letters',
    put: false,
    pull: 'clone',
  },
  setData: function(dataTransfer, element) {
    dataTransfer.setData('text', element.textContent);
  },
  sort: false
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well, technically all job is done programmatically... `$cloneEl.remove(); $('#widgets-1 > div').eq(5).after($cloneEl)`

Comment: @Justinas: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra Clone desired element, remove original from DOM, append cloned element to desired position. Apply transitions/animations if needed smooth movement.